# MYSQL ways to represent '1970-1-1 0:0:0'

Tags: mysql, datetime, timestamp

Out of interest, are there any other ways of representing the timestamp `'1970-1-1 0:0:0'` other than `from_unixtime(0)`?

In PostgreSQL there is `'epoch'::timestamp`. Would there be an equivalent in MySQL which is as concise?

Comment: I think this is a cool question because FROM_UNIXTIME(0) is so badly taken for granted,

Comment: Out of interest... why would you want a specific way to represent `1970-01-01 00:00:00`?  And, by that, do you actually mean the time `1970-01-01T00:00:00Z`? Or what, exactly?   It sounds as if you are using it as a magic literal where you should be using `NULL`.  I can think of no valid reason for this.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot, I use a 3rd-party software which exports our data to this DB in this format. I totally agree with you that it should be `NULL` but there's nothing I can really do

Comment: I think I'd be inclined to attempt to use a trigger to try to fix this data as it's inserted... but failing that, I guess you're looking for an expression to use in equality comparisons?  If that's it, then what about a stored function that simply returns that value?  I use those to emulate "constants" in views and stored procedures fairly routinely.

Answer (score 2):

[FROM_UNIXTIME(0)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime) is not really `'1970-01-01 00:00:00'`.

It can be skewed by timezone and daylight saving time.

For example, I live in the New York area, which is -5 from GMT. My system says how and why:

```
mysql> SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP('1970-01-01 00:00:00');
+---------------------------------------+
| UNIX_TIMESTAMP('1970-01-01 00:00:00') |
+---------------------------------------+
|                                 18000 |
+---------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select FROM_UNIXTIME(0);
+---------------------+
| FROM_UNIXTIME(0)    |
+---------------------+
| 1969-12-31 19:00:00 |
+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

It is actually off by 5 hours (18000 seconds)

To correct it, move forward one day and back `HOUR(FROM_UNIXTIME(0))` hours

```
mysql> SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(0) + INTERVAL 1 DAY - INTERVAL HOUR(FROM_UNIXTIME(0)) HOUR DT;
+---------------------+
| DT                  |
+---------------------+
| 1970-01-01 00:00:00 |
+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

or simply go forward 5 hours

```
mysql> SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(0) + INTERVAL (24 - HOUR(FROM_UNIXTIME(0))) HOUR DT;
+---------------------+
| DT                  |
+---------------------+
| 1970-01-01 00:00:00 |
+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

This formula should work in any timezone

Answer (score 1):

Are you east of Greenwich or west of it?  That date, *after adjusting for timezone* cannot be represented in half the world.

`YEAR` has a huge span.

`DATETIME` has a huge span.

`TIMESTAMP` is limited to ~1970... to ~2038...